# How to upload images to PARSE by using Titanium

Tags: android, image, titanium, parse-platform, image-uploading

I'm making an app that require upload images function and also a image view function.
The question I'm having now is how to upload images to Parse, and how to get it?
Heard that we need to encode the image file to string before we upload it, however I have no luck to find the code to encode.
Below is how I post data to Parse. However, its not applicable to `images`.

```
    var parseURL = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User";

    var userNameTemp = userName_input.value;//text from textField


    var postJson = {
           username : userNameTemp + '',
       }


    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(e) {
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText);//check what the parse.com send back
            var responseObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);



        },
        onerror: function(e) {
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
            //alert('Error Getting Key Values');
        },
        timeout:10000  /* in milliseconds */
      });//end of HttpClient object creation, xhr.

    xhr.open("POST", parseURL);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'myAppId');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'myRestApiId');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(postJson));
});
```

Any information related will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the documentation here:

https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-uploading

You put a name in the URL (doen't have to be unique as it gets given a unique prefix), set the content type and post the file in the body.

```
var parseURL = "https://api.parse.com/1/files/pic.jpg";

// ... [snip] create your xhr [/snip] ...

xhr.open("POST", parseURL);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'myAppId');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'myRestApiId');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
xhr.send(imageData);
```

You'll want to capture the output as it will give you the correct name to allow you to link it to other objects in Parse.